# Pointer value changing

Tags: c, pointers, semantics

INPUT FILE:

```
JOHN 9999999999
MEENA 9888888888
RIA 8718218218
SONIA 7777777777
FINCH 1234567890
```

- I want to create a circular linked list by appending contents of file into list.I create a sentinal with "NO VALUE" entry into it.
- When I tested my code in gdb p->next->name at the end of while loop in uploadAddresses() is showing Finch.How is it possible?p value is remaining same only temp value is changing after each iteration.

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>    
  #include<stdlib.h>    
  #include<string.h>    
  #define MAXPHONENO 100

  //Variables declaration 
  struct Contact {
    char *name;
    char *mobileno;
    struct Contact *next;
  };
  typedef struct Contact Contact;    
  typedef Contact* PHBOOK;

  //Function declaration
  PHBOOK createAddressBook();
  PHBOOK uploadAddresses(PHBOOK pb,char *name);

  //Implementation
  PHBOOK createAddressBook(){    
    PHBOOK pb = (PHBOOK)malloc(sizeof(Contact));   
    pb->name = "NO ENTRY";    
    pb->mobileno = "NO ENTRY";    
    pb->next = pb;    
    return pb;    
  }


  PHBOOK uploadAddresses(PHBOOK p,char *fname){
    PHBOOK temp = p;
    char mob[20],name[20];
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s",name,mob)!=EOF){
      temp->next = (PHBOOK)malloc(sizeof(Contact));    
      temp = temp->next;    
      temp->name = name;    
      temp->mobileno = mob;    
      printf("%s %s\n",name,mob);    
    }    
    temp->next = p;    
    return p;    
  }   

  int main(){    
    PHBOOK pb = createAddressBook();    
    pb = uploadAddresses(pb,"/home/user/names_mobile");    
    return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Where is the code of function `createAddressBook`?

Comment: i have posted code for createAddressBook() now

Comment: If you want a circular linked list, why are you pointing only to the next item and not also to the previous one? Also, to define the last element of a list, the pointer to the next element is used to be defined as `null`, not to itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp->name = name;
```

You only assigned the pointer to `temp->name`.

This pointer point to a local variable.

Edit:

In your case char name[20] is used by fscanf to contain the input name, its context changed in each loop. And it would be "Finch" in it at the end of while loop.

As we know "temp->name" point to "char name[20]" with "Finch" contained, that's why you saw it.

Comment: You might like to add an explanation why it isn't a good idea to store references to local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
temp->name = name;
temp->mobileno = mob;
```

To:

```
temp->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
temp->mobileno = malloc(strlen(mob)+1);
strcpy(temp->name,name);
strcpy(temp->mobileno,mob);
```

Comment: Correct, you have defined `name` and `mobileno` as a pointer to a char. It's strange that you aren't receiving some segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

malloc some memory for

```
char *name;
char *mobileno;
```

as well this will solve your problem.

```
PHBOOK uploadAddresses(PHBOOK p,char *fname){

PHBOOK temp = p;
char mob[20],name[20];

FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"r");


  while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s",name,mob)!=EOF)
  {
    temp->next = (PHBOOK)malloc(sizeof(Contact));  
    temp = temp->next; 
    temp->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME) ;    
    temp->mobileno = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_PHNO) ;  

   strcpy(temp->name,name);
    strcpy(temp->mobileno,mob);

  }    
    temp->next = p;    
    return p;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Improved code:**

Note <%ms> modifier, which dynamically allocates space for string. Also file have to be closed, otherwise resource leak occurs.

```
    PHBOOK uploadAddresses(PHBOOK p,char *fname){
      PHBOOK temp = p;
      char *mob,*name;
      FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"r");

      if (!fp)
        return temp;

      while (fscanf(fp,"%ms %ms",&name,&mob)!=EOF) {  
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(Contact));       
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->name = name;    
        temp->mobileno = mob;    
        printf("%s %s\n",name,mob);    
      }

      fclose(fp);
      temp->next = p;    
      return p;  
    }
```